# Stop Setinterval after 1 run

Tags: settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I've made a little script which places a button in an ID 'AddToCartLayer' which is loaded dynamically.

```
var myVar;
myVar = setInterval(str, 1000);

function str() {
  var str = '<a href="google.nl" style="font-size:18px;" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Google</a>',
    div = document.getElementById( 'addToCartLayer' );

div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
}
```

Now, I can't really figure out how I can stop the script from running once the button is placed in the ID.

Could someone please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

i think **setTimeout()** will work.

Comment: Thanks! And how would I write the code for it? I'm not familiar with setTimeout().

Comment: change setInterval to setTimeout or check this:- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: make a +1 on this answer if you like and mark it complete

Comment: I think I cheered to early. The function doens't place the button in the id when the id is loaded. So I would like to use setInterval with a limit of 1 run.